# Animejs 3.2.1: Anime stagger not working with vue transition-group

Tags: vue.js, animejs

I am trying to create a staggering animation effect in my project. I am working with vue 3 and animejs 3.2.1.
Basically, I dynamically rendered a list like so:

```
<div class="products-container">
    <transition-group class="flex-container" tag="ul" appear @before-enter="beforeEnterCans" @enter="enterCans">
      <li class="dynamic-flex-children" v-for="cokeImage in cokeImages" :key="cokeImage.id">
        <img :src="cokeImage.src" :alt="cokeImage.title" class="can-image">
        <p>{{cokeImage.title}}</p>
      </li>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
```

This generates a list of eight items which I have in a layout in a grid using flex.

```
.products-container{
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.flex-container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5% 10%;
}
.dynamic-flex-children{
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
.dynamic-flex-children img{
  width: 40%;
}
.dynamic-flex-children p{
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

As you can see, the `<ul>` have the vue animation hooks attached to the `<transition-group>`.
In the component instance, I now used animejs to try to implement a staggering effect for each `<li>` when the list enters the screen

```
<script>
import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';
export default {
  name: 'Products',
  data(){
    return {
      cokeImages: [
        { title: 'Cocacola Life', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/cocacola-life.png'), id: 1 },
        { title: 'Cocacola Zero', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/cocacola-zero.png'), id: 2 },
        { title: 'Diet Coke', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/diet-coke.png'), id: 3 },
        { title: 'Cocacola Classic', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/classic-coke-two.png'), id: 4 },
        { title: 'New Cocacola', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/classic-cocacola.png'), id: 5 },
        { title: 'Vanilla', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/cocacola-vanilla.png'), id: 6 },
        { title: 'Cocacola Light', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/cocacola-light.png'), id: 7 },
        { title: 'Cocacola Cherry', src: require('@/assets/cocacola-cans/cocacola-cherry.png'), id: 8 }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    beforeEnterCans(el){
      el.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)"
      el.style.opacity = 0
    },
    enterCans(el){
      anime({
        targets: el,
        opacity: 1,
        translateX: 0,
        delay: anime.stagger(200, {start: 100}),
        easing: 'easeInOutSine'
      })
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

For whatever reason, the list deosn't stagger when they transition in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and errors, I found the problem.

```
enter(el){
      anime({
        targets: ".dynamic-flex-children",
        duration: 700,
        opacity: 1,
        translateX: 0,
        delay: anime.stagger(100, {start: 100, direction: "reverse"}),
        easing: 'easeInOutSine'
      })
    }
```

anime.js uses classes to target elements. I was passing `el` to the targets options instead of the shared class name of all the dynamically generated `<li>` tags. I just changed the targets option from `el` to the shared class name `.dynamic-flex-children` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

el is a single element, so since you aren't passing a list of elements to target, the stagger does not work.

My solution is to pass the index as a data attribute :

```
<li class="dynamic-flex-children" v-for="(cokeImage, index) in cokeImages" :key="cokeImage.id" :data-index="index">
        <img :src="cokeImage.src" :alt="cokeImage.title" class="can-image">
        <p>{{cokeImage.title}}</p>
</li>
```

and then set the delay like this:

```
enterCans(el){

  let delay = el.dataset.index * 100;


  anime({
    targets: el,
    opacity: 1,
    translateX: 0,
    delay: delay,
    easing: 'easeInOutSine'
  })
}
```